Chrome extension to download current page HTML
I need to downwload HTML (Only HTML and not CSS/images etc) of the current page.  I should be able to give name to the downloaded file. I will read that HTML using python script and extract some information. I am unable to open webpage thru tools like selenium, playwright etc because of protection measures by site.  I basically want to avoid inspecting, selecting and saving HTML.  There are a lots of questions on this topic to write an extension.  I am looking for already available extension that I can use. I will be repeating this process on multiple URLs so file naming like file1.html, file2.html, file3.html should be allowed.

Although this question is off-topic on Stack Overflow, with a little editing it will be on topic on Software Recommendations SE: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

When I looked about a year ago there weren't any extensions available which could handle the "because of protection measures by site" issue, so there's no point looking. You can check this in the webstore. I wrote an extension myself that copies the DOM, and so avoids page reloads and security problems. This isn't difficult, but only works for Chrome.

If you're going to process the file after the fact, why doesn't this work: Ctrl+U, Ctrl+S, Enter?

Thanks Rand'Chris. This short-cut works as I need.
